# maximum size of a group (PSGroupSpecifier) Title string in Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization, settings.bundle

There seems to be some limit on the size of group titles that you can put into your app's settings screen (I'm using it to put a block of text into the setting screen, rather than as just as title).

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007009-SW1) doesn't seem to mentioned any limit, and I've not turned up anything whilst searching google.

If you exceed the limit, your string just seems to be completely ignored, or sometimes the whole strings file seems to be ignored and you just see the pre-translation tag. Does anyone know what the limit might be? The limit is possibly somewhere around a screenful of text on the iPad.

Comment: People asking this question might also find the answer to "Best way to add license section to iOS settings bundled" ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle ) interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having stumbled upon this same problem and after an hour of trial and error, I found out that the limit is around 1300 chars.

One obvious and easy solution is to split the string up in various groups, and possibly using FooterText instead of Title to make it smaller.

Comment: Thanks! Splitting it does seem the best way to go - I wrote a script to do the splitting and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle  - I use it for adding open source license text, but the script is probably actually fairly general purpose.