# Where to display disclaimer in my ios application

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have developed an iphone application which will be available in Apple Store in a few weeks.
I have used some public libraries and some public source code from internet.
(Like enormego image gallery,library. And apple's Reachability class from Apple's official samples)
Do i have to display any reference for them in somewhere in my application?(Like an about page)
If yes where do you suggest to display that reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

- [best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle)

I use something similar to that to automatically generate a settings bundle component to display the licenses in the settings panel. That seems to be the general way of doing this - Facebook do it like that as well for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, this would most likely depend on the License Agreements for each of the libraries and third party source code items you've incorporated into your work.  Take some time to check their license agreements out.

Unofficially, since you're likely not in the U.S.A., you're out of reach of the court system and you yourself personally can't be sued.  Whoever hired you could be, though.

As for where you should display any License Agreements, citations or disclaimers... that's completely application specific.  You could display it in an "About" view or in the Settings Panel (which is a great suggestion by Matt in his answer) or in an info disclosure view (the kind that flips into view).  It's completely up to you.