# What's the proper way to include license text in Settings app under iOS 7?

Tags: ios, plist, ios7, settings.bundle

Traditionally, I've used group element titles in my Settings.bundle file, as suggested in the answer to this question:

[best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507)

However, under iOS 7, this technique leads to a portion of the text appearing above the top of the page.  You can manually scroll up to view it in some cases, but it still looks very unprofessional.

The current release of Apple's iBooks app shows its "Acknowledgements" setting properly, so there must be a way to do this properly under iOS 7.

What is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before iOS 7 you could set the license as the title of a group. By replacing "Title" with "FooterText" the issue in iOS 7 can be solved:

> "Type" - String - "PSGroupSpecifier"
> "FooterText" - String - Your license

Comment: That did the trick.  Only glitch was that "PSGroupSpecifier" shows up as "Group" unless you check "Show Raw Keys/Values" from the control-click popup.