# Dynamic text block in iOS App Settings

Tags: ios, plist

I want to send some log data to the ios app settings menu. I have dynamic text fields that I can change from that app working, but I need a text block now.

What I need to do is have a menu item that has a child view. That part too I have working. You click on `View Logs` from my app settings menu and it takes me to a blank page right now. How can I add a large dynamic text block? I have tried adding a `Group` and setting the `Key` to `FooterText` which I think is what I need to do. I can specify static text in there right now.

I don't know how to make it dynamic though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on what you are trying to do here (maybe clarify?). If you need a large text view then why not consider UITextView. You can jam essentially as much text in there as you want.

Settings is really not meant to serve as a read-write repository in the manner you describe. It is really focused on write infrequently, read many (think LDAP). However, you can make a lot of text data available through settings if that's what you want. Since the fields in settings don't support large quantities of text data, you might consider this approach. Even though it talks about 'licenses and attribution' you could apply this to logfiles as well.

[best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle)

Comment: this is for the app settings as in tap settings on your phone and scroll down to the app. I think this is only achived through the plist files. Essentially what I want to do is add a menu item and on the child view will contain log information that my app sends. I can already change properties in text fields, there just doesn't seem to be an option for a large amount of text.