# Implementing Script at Build Phase in Xcode

Tags: xcode, perl

I've been attempting to implement the Perl script found here: [best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507)

I've followed the instructions given to a T but when I go to run my project I get the following error after changing the permissions of the script to CHMOD 755:

```
No such file or directory at ./LicenseScript.pl line 10.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

Why won't my app compile?

Comment: What is on line 10 then?

Comment: Well if blank lines are counted then it is: `open(my $outfh, '>', $out) or die $!;` otherwise, the tenth line of code is `<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">`

Comment: Yes, it will be the 10th line in the file, no matter what is before it. And that error with that line means that the path in `$out` contains a directory that does not exist. E.g. `$out = "foo/bar/baz.txt"`, but `foo/bar` does not exist.

Comment: Now, in the script `$out` is declared as `my $out = "../Settings.bundle/en.lproj/Acknowledgements.strings";`. I don't believe that Acknowledgements.strings is supposed to exist prior to running the script based on the instructions.

Comment: What TLP is trying to tell you is: When you open a file for writing perl will create the file if it doesn't exist, right?  Wrong.  open() will not create *directories*, so unless the directory `../Settings.bundle/en.lproj/` exists beforehand, then perl will not create your file.  The error message is telling you that, in fact, the directory does not exist.