# Plist Text Formatting

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I've been working on an 'Acknowledgements' child pane for my iOS app with varying success. I first tried to implement the script found here: [best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507) but couldn't get the script to run at build time so I resorted to manually generating my Plist file. I currently have the following Plist file that is working almost as I'd like it: https://github.com/andrewlumley/Acknowledgements/blob/master/Acknowledgements.plist

But when I open the panel on the iOS Simulator the child pane looks like this:

[image]

My question is, how do I alter my .plist such that the text is formatted as paragraphs rather than the broken left-aligned format that I have now?

Comment: Use an `.html` (or other common formatted text file) rather than `.plist` file?  What advantage does using a `.plist` file give?

Comment: Well I believe that child panes in the settings bundle only accept .plist files and being my first iOS app I decided to use the default since it appears that a .plist is often used for this purpose.

Comment: Get rid of the unwanted newlines in the plist file.

Comment: I'm surprised that didn't occur to me, thanks for pointing that out!