# swift ios paypal sdk, missing settings.bundle in project

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

im trying to integrate the paypal mobile sdk into my swift project.

Im new to swift and i have almost no knowledge in objective-c.

i followed this:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#if-you-use-cocoapods-then-add-these-lines-to-your-podfile

I installed the sdk with cocoapods.

Now im at the step of adding licenses to the app using this tutorial
 `setting up your Settings.bundle`:
[best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507)

But in my project theres no `settings.bundle` group

In my supporting files group theres only the `info.plist`.

Where is that group located? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

It was listed in `create file > ios > resources > settings bundle`.