# How can I add Open Source Code Attributions with Licenses to my Settings Bundle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, settings.bundle

I've heard when using open source code, that they need to be visibly accessible in your app or you need to include them in your settings bundle.

How can I include them in my settings bundle?

1) What exactly is necessary to be included? The actual LICENSE file that comes with the open source code, or just the text inside it?

2) How does it get stored? Do they all get bunched together, or as separate elements of an XML file or something?

3) How is it written to the setting bundle? What is the syntax/code to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this other stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507)