# Settings.bundle - plist: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: xcode, plist, settings.bundle

I've used a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507) in Xcode 8 / iOS 10 to generate an acknowledge section in the settings bundle.

The script producing an Acknowledgements.plist file that gives the error message

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

when I try to open it in Xcode. When I open `Acknowledgements.plist` file with textEdit it looks OK on first sight ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
<key>Type</key>
<string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
<key>FooterText</key>
<string>knobcontrol</string>
<key>Type</key>
<string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
<key>FooterText</key>
<string>knobcontrol2</string>
</array>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Acknowledgements</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've tried some of the comments according to the script but could not find what is wrong with the plist - can anybody have a look at the file? I don't have enough reputation to post comments to the script posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<key>...</key>` value pairs within an `<array>`.

Make it a `<dict>` instead:

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
        <dict>    <- dict, not array
            ...
        </dict>    <- dict, not array
        <key>StringsTable</key>
        <string>Acknowledgements</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```