# Where to add font license in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, custom-font

I'm working on an iOS project (XCode 8 / Swift 3) that uses a custom font (Oswald). When I downloaded the fonts from Google Fonts they came with a text file, the SIL Open Font License, which I'm supposed to include in the project. Should I just copy this text file into my bundle? Or should I add some comments into specific view controllers? Not sure what the standard procedure is in this case. Hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OP didn't ask what can/cannot be done. He asked if there is a common place for the license/copyright text to be shown in the app -- ie. as the license says, "... easily viewed by the user" -> where is considered normal for this in iOS?  If you're going to **yell at someone in bold and treat them like a child by telling them to read something multiple times**, it's best if you read the question from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

What about in the Settings app? See this related question & answer: [best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle)